# Facebook feed server side only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find a solution : depending on the privacy settings, I want to list on a website some status of my facebook page .

Using PHP SDK I tried many things, but the request to the MY_PAGE/feed webservice doesn't give me the privacy parameters. So I think my access token isn't good.

I don't want to have a client-side authentification because the user doesn't matter in my case, I just want my facebook page feed, with the privacy parameter.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an offline access token, which can be abit tricky to get the hands on.
More in depth about here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
However you still need atleast one user interaction where the user agree to give you application offline access.